# Is it fine to violate Composition Over Inheritance when necessary?

Tags: c++, inheritance, composition

I have a set of classes:

```cpp
// This is #included from another header file
// I don't want to inherit this, because it ain't my code
class DrawableObject;

class Animal {
    DrawableObject obj;
    // Does not define run() or swim()
};

class Cat : public Animal {
    void run() { /* Calls obj.setPosition() and other stuff */ }
};

class Dog : public Animal {
    void run() { /* Calls obj.setPosition() and other stuff */ }
    void swim() { /* Calls obj.setPosition() and other stuff */ }
};

class Dolphin : public Animal {
    void swim() { /* Calls obj.setPosition() and other stuff */ }
};
```

Here, `Dog::run()` and `Cat::run()` happen to use the exact same code, and `Dog::swim()` and `Dolphin::swim()` also use the same code. Instead of copy-pasting code all over the place, I would like to reuse it. The sensible solution seems to be adding intermediate subclasses between the base class (`Animal`) and the concrete classes (`Cat/Dog/Dolphin`):

```
       /-> RunnableAnimal --> Cat
       |                  \
Animal-|                  |-> Dog
       |                  /
       \-> SwimmableAnimal -> Dolphin
```

The question being: Am I going against the "Composition over Inheritance" rule? If so, is this perfectly fine, or is there a way to adhere to CoI while achieving code reuse?

Note: I **don't** need or want polymorphism--when I use `run()`, I'm always calling it using the concrete (`Cat/Dog/Sloth`) classes, instead of the base `Animal` class.

Comment: What does that have to do with _composition_?

Comment: If the inheritance isn't virtual (which by the sound of it it should not be), then you'll have _two_ copies of the `Animal` base in your leaf classes. Maybe a CRTP-style approach would be better for providing those common functions?

Comment: Alternatively, you could have separate classes Runner and Swimmer, give the animals an instance of as far as needed, and the run/swim functions of the animals would just call the appropriate functions (or maybe `operator()`) of the respective aggregates.

Comment: Off-topic: Actually, even though disliking water, cats are (very!) good swimmers as well... If we aren't speaking of house cats, but in more general terms, then there are even cats *loving* water (tigers!).

Comment: Next variant: Dog, Cat and Dolphin all inherit Animal, Dog and Cat additionally inherit `Runner`, Dog and Dolphin (disregarding my previous comment) inherit `Swimmer` (so Dog in the end has 3 direct base classes).

Comment: Commenting your edit: You need to make `obj` protected, otherwise even without moving common code to separate classes the derived animals won't be able to access it...

Answer (score 4):

Better inheritance pattern:

```
          /–––––––––– Cat
         /          /
        /    Runner
       /            \
Animal –––––––––––––– Dog
       \            /
        \    Swimmer
         \          \
          \–––––––––– Dolphin
```

You avoid the diamond pattern you introduced with your approach.

Instead of inheriting, you might instead aggregate a `Runner`/`Swimmer` instance within the animals where needed and let the animals' functions just delegate to the members.

Just a minor issue regarding your model: It doesn't really reflect reality, actually, cats, although disliking water, are quite good swimmers as well...

**Edit:** As `Runner` and `Swimmer` need access to `Animal`'s members: You can provide this via [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern); added a demonstration below:

```
class Animal
{
protected:
    int n = 7;
};

template <typename T>
class Swimmer
{
public:
    void swim()
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<T*>(this)->n << std::endl;
    }
};

class Dolphin : public Animal, public Swimmer<Dolphin>
{
    friend class Swimmer; // n is protected!
    // (alternatively, Swimmer might already be a friend of Animal)
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Dolphin d;
    d.swim();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given this you can code `bool isSwimmer(const Animal* a) { return dynamic_cast<Swimmer*>(a); }` and things like that.

Comment: My implementation of `swim()` and `run()` requires direct access to member variables and functions (`age`, `health`, etc.) in `Animal`. Is this possible when they are defined in `Runner` and `Swimmer`?

Comment: @PhilKang It might be more appropriate to move those variables to Runner/Swimmer classes. If not: `class Runner { public: Runner(Animal& animal) : animal(animal) { }; private: Animal& animal; }; Cat::Cat() : Runner(*this) { }`

Comment: @mirko enciuraging dynamic cast is not what I call a feature.

Comment: Acon; consider CRTP for swimmer/runner.

Comment: @Aconcagua Impossible. The Animal class holds a member variable: `DrawableObject obj`. The `run()` and `swim()` methods directly interact with `obj`. Since the implementation of `DrawableObject` is out of my control, I'd rather not make `Animal` inherit from it. I will update OP to include this detail.

Comment: @PhilKang It *is* possible; via [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) you can access the other members; added a demonstration for.